# What AudioFormat.Encoding constructor parameter means?

Tags: java, audio, encoding, javasound

The manual [does not answer this question](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioFormat.Encoding.html#AudioFormat.Encoding(java.lang.String)): it says "the name of the new type of encoding".

Is this just an arbitrary name like filename? Or this is some predefined name, like in `Charset.forName()` method?

In latter case where can I find the list of supported sound encodings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check our the source code for: [AudioFormat.java](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-5.0/javax/sound/sampled/AudioFormat.Encoding.java.html). At the bottom of the class it constructs four pre-defined encodings:

1. PCM_SIGNED = new Encoding("PCM_SIGNED");
2. PCM_UNSIGNED = new Encoding("PCM_UNSIGNED");
3. ULAW = new Encoding("ULAW");
4. ALAW = new Encoding("ALAW");

The String is used in the `equals()` and `hashCode()` implementations for `AudioFormat.Encoding`, so it certainly is intended to serve the purpose of a unique identifier for the encoding.